# Check correspondence of rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this one (but bigger):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1159, 1272, 1287, 1215, 1406, 1353, 1339), L1_agree = c(T, T, F, T, F, T, F), percent_left_click = c(50, 40, 30, 60, 40, 30, 90), misfit = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

I want to generate an output which tells me if the items which have a `FALSE` value in the L1_agree column also have a `100` value in the percent_left_click column or a `1` value in the "misfit" column.

I created a vector containing the items which have `FALSE` values for L1_agree:

```
L1_disagree <- subset(df, L1_agree == FALSE)$id
```

But I can't figure out how I could use this vector to check the values in the other columns.

Can anyone help?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` for this, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(check = case_when(
    L1_agree == FALSE & (percent_left_click == 100 | misfit == 1) ~ "Yes",
    TRUE ~ "No"
  ))
```

**Output:**

```
    id L1_agree percent_left_click misfit check
1 1159     TRUE                 50      1    No
2 1272     TRUE                 40      0    No
3 1287    FALSE                 30      0    No
4 1215     TRUE                 60      0    No
5 1406    FALSE                 40      1   Yes
6 1353     TRUE                 30      0    No
7 1339    FALSE                 90      0    No
```